# Replace not working when Looping through an Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, replace

Working on a project and I have a need to replace a '`path prefix`' with a different prefix. Automating the copying of files and then I will do using those files locally. Rather than making new variables I figured I would re-purpose old ones I would not need after the copy is complete. Ran into an issue with doing a replace when looping through the Array. I was able to find a solution for this particular scenario but would like to understand why my loops were not working

No errors are shown to give me an indication why it is not working.

Any help on understanding why the replace isn't working when looping would be helpful

**Sample code of how I am building paths**

```
[string]$Root_Path = "\\Main_Blah_Path\"

[string]$Software = $Root_Path + "Software\"

[string]$Adobe_Reader = $Software + "Adobe_Reader\"
[string]$Firefox = $Software + "Firefox\"
[string]$Google_Chrome = $Software + "Google_Chrome\"

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$List_Of_Software = @(
    $Adobe_Reader
    $Firefox
    $Google_Chrome
)
```

**Example of the ways I have done the replacement. These work and will write the desired output to the console**

```
foreach ($Path in $List_Of_Software) {
    $Path -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'
}
$List_Of_Software | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'}
```

**Example of failures I am having. I cannot replace and save the data into itself to do a replacement. I couldn't get `.replace` to work at all**

```
foreach ($Path in $List_Of_Software) {
    $Path = $Path -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'
}
$List_Of_Software | ForEach-Object {$_ = $_ -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'}

foreach ($Path in $List_Of_Software) {
    $Path.Replace('\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\')
}
```

**Solution I am using for my current scenario but I can foresee a few things in my future where this method may not be a viable option**

```
$List_Of_Software = $List_Of_Software -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to assign the results of the replacement back to the variable when you're looping the array. Try:

```
$List_of_software = $List_Of_Software | 
  ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\\\\Main_Blah_Path\\','C:\Folder\'}
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. I have more questions though. I thought when you looped through an array it select the object/index, you can make a change and save it back into itself, therefore, it would be update in the array. Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, but use a for loop, not a foreach. That way you can modify each array element. When you send the array down a pipeline, the pipeline variable `$_` holds a copy (I assume) of the element, not its actual value, nor a reference to it.

Comment: Is`foreach` not the `for` loop in PS? When I piped the Array to `ForEach-Object` I was able to use `$_` but the result didn't change.

Comment: No, for loops and foreach are not the same thing. You cannot pipe to a for loop. The reason you weren't able to change `$_` in the pipeline is explained in my previous comment.